# How to separate a string of repeating characters?

Tags: python

All continuous groups of characters must be grouped together and put into a list. For example, if I have this string:

```
1112221121
```

I would want to split this into a list:

```
['111', '222', '11', '2', '1']`
```

Another example would be

```
0011100000
```

Output: `['00', '111', '00000']`

This is what I've come up with:

```
In [146]: t = '0011100000'
     ...: out = [] 
     ...: prev = None
     ...: for c in t:
     ...:     if c != prev:
     ...:         prev = c
     ...:         out.append('')
     ...:     out[-1] += c
     ...:     

In [147]: out
Out[147]: ['00', '111', '00000']
```

Is there a simpler solution? I think I am overthinking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` does just that:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby('1112221121')]
['111', '222', '11', '2', '1']
```

Comment: Is this a simpler alternative to the regex in the dupe, according to you? I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If and when there is a simple non-regex approach, I tend to prefer those, since they read clearer and expertise on regex for your code maintainers may vary.

Comment: groupby is probably faster than regex, yes.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for this.